# Need to push the escape key programmatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to be able to simulate pressing the Escape key in a Flutter web application.

Any help would be valued.

Comment: This is the only resource I could find that seems marginally relevant, but it's unclear how to actually implement it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/webdriver.sync_io/Keyboard-class.html#constructors

Comment: The [sendKeys method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/webdriver.sync_io/Keyboard/sendKeys.html) seems to be functional without any implementation?

Comment: @JustLearnedIt If you understand how that works, please share the code to push Escape

Comment: `keyboard.sendKeys(Keyboard.escape);`

Comment: Where is 'keyboard' defined? @JustLearnedIt     What do you need to import in order for this line to actually work?

Comment: That's the problem. There is a constructor for `Keyboard`, but it requires more arguments.

Comment: @JustLearnedIt I'm not sure what you're saying.  If you have some working code to press the escape key, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in integration tests. Check the docs.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

Comment: I'm asking about a very specific thing - pressing the Escape key. I'm expecting one or more lines of code as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try html.window.dispatchEvent() method inside a .dart file to achieve this.

1. Step 1 - Import html

```html
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

2. Step 2 - Call below method

```html
html.window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'Escape' }));
```

References for keys - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values